# Boolean function not returning proper value

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using following function which uses boolean value.

```
int recFound=0;
        public Boolean CheckUser(String uName,String password)
        {
            try
            {
                statement=conn.createStatement();


                resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select count(*) from UserMaster where username LIKE'"+uName+"' and password LIKE'"+password+"'");

                    if(resultSet.getRow()>0)
                    {
                        recFound=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        recFound=0;
                    }



            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                recFound=0;
            }
            if(recFound == 0)
            {
            return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
}
```

I am calling this function through:

```
boolean isValidUser=con.CheckUser(etLoginID.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString());
                if(isValidUser)
                {
                    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Messages.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
```

When i pass this function proper values its not making `recFound=1;`

And in last condition although recFound==0 it enters in else condition and returns true.

But while assigning this value to caller functions return value it assigns false.

Means it makes , `boolean isValidUser=con.CheckUser(etLoginID.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString());`  to be false.

```
isValidUser should get true in such case.
```

Please help me.

Comment: resultSet is a cursor......??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Shrimant Bajirao Peshawe - I,

change the statement "**if(resultSet.getRow()>0)**" to "**if(resultSet. next ())**" then try it.

Reference : [Refer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)

Comment: getRow() function is returning 0 each time, while record does exists. It should return me 1 (to satisfy >0 condition

Answer (score 1):

you are calling a boolean function in your CheckUser method so its returns true or false value..

Jo just returns **true** value in that function.

you can also check it with:

```
if(isValidUser==true)
            {
                Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Messages.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

and print a value **isValidUser** in log that which value it is getting

Comment: while returning it returns true, but while catching it takes false

Comment: in debugger when i seen its false

Answer (score 1):

Try Follwing code...

```
int recFound = 0;
public boolean CheckUser(String uName, String password) {
    try {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select count(*) from UserMaster where username LIKE '" + uName + "' and password LIKE '" + password + "'");
        if (resultSet.getRow() > 0) {
            recFound = 1;
        } else {
            recFound = 0;
        }
        if (recFound > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
if(con.CheckUser(etLoginID.getText().toString(), etPassword.getText().toString())) {
    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Messages.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: getRow() function is returning 0 each time, while record does exists. It should return me 1 (to satisfy >0 condition

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the 
**isValidUser** to false at the begining

also log the value of **resultSet.getRow()** and **recFound** before returning it caller.

you can also try to use cusrsor like below

```
int recFound=0;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
        public Boolean CheckUser(String uName,String password)
        {
            try
            {

               String sql="select count(*) from UserMaster where username LIKE'"+uName+"' and password LIKE'"+password+"'";
               Log.i(TAG,"Executing Query : "+sql);
               mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
               Log.i(TAG,"Query Executed Successfully");
               if(mCur!=null)
               {
                        recFound=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        recFound=0;
                    }



            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                recFound=0;
            }

            if(recFound == 0)
            {
            return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
}
```

Comment: getRow() function is returning 0 each time, while record does exists. It should return me 1 (to satisfy >0 condition

Answer (score 1):

Replace code

```
 if(resultSet.getRow()>0){
      recFound=1;
  } else {
      recFound=0;
  }
```

to

```
  if(resultSet.next()){
      return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: getRow() function is returning 0 each time, while record does exists. It should return me 1 (to satisfy >0 condition

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
               if(resultSet.getRow()>0)
                {
                    recFound=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    recFound=0;
                }
```

**to:**

```
               if(resultSet.getRow()>0)
                {   
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

Remove conditions checking recFound in `catch()`

This should solve your problem.

Comment: getRow() function is returning 0 each time, while record does exists. It should return me 1 (to satisfy >0 condition

Comment: Use `resultSet.moveToNext()`. I am assuming resultSet is cursor